# Android App won't start on boot

Tags: android, android-manifest, boot, receiver

I read loast of tutorials about how to make an app start at system boot ([Link](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/), [Link](http://blogmobile.itude.com/2012/02/20/automatically-starting-an-android-application-on-boot/)...).

My receiver looks like this, the rest like described in the tutorials:

```
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But my app just won't start... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too stuipid!

You need to add the full path to the receiver class:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.mypackage.whatever.BootUpReceiver"
```

Comment: `.BootUpReceiver` should work, if it's in the root of your app's package. Otherwise you'll need something like `.receivers.BootUpReceiver` if your receiver is `<app.package.name>.receivers.BootUpReceiver`.

Comment: You sure it wasn't the permission entry causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> My receiver looks like this, the rest like described in the tutorials

Your `<receiver>` element is incorrect. You are requiring that the sender of the broadcast hold the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, which may or may not be true. Please remove the `android:permission` attribute. If needed, add `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` as a `<uses-permission>` element, to say that *you* wish to hold that permission.